# How to sort using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT. This is my Sample XML. How to sort the events in the order of eventtime in descending order

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Event>
    <EventTime>1645554600000</EventTime>
    <UserID>user1@domain.com</UserID>
    <msg>Message1</msg>
</Event>
<Event>
    <EventTime>1645607692000</EventTime>
    <UserID>user2@domain.com</UserID>
    <msg>Message2</msg>
</Event>
<Event>
    <EventTime>1645607704000</EventTime>
    <UserID>user3@domain.com</UserID>
    <msg>Message3</msg>
</Event>
```

The below template is fetching me only the first event

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My XML Data</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>time</th>
        <th>msg</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Event">
      <xsl:sort select="EventTime" order="descending"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="EventTime"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="msg"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. -- P.S. The input you show is not a well-formed XML document (does not have a single root element) and cannot be processed by XSLT at all.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the response. The structure of XML output from our application is as described above. Yes, there is no root element, yet we are doing some operations on this XML to display content in different formats. However, with this, I want to display in the reverse order and hence I am finding it difficult to sort by eventime

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? I am not able to reproduce the result you report using your code; all I get is an error - as expected: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyfAiCr

Comment: I tried in w3Schools online processor for my above example.

Comment: Not with the code above you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="Event">
   <xsl:sort select="EventTime" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
   ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: with the above I am getting first event only

Comment: Then you've probably got the context wrong. Since your input document isn't well formed and you haven't given your complete stylesheet code it's hard to know how to help you.